How to write unit test case for gocql
package main 

import "github.com/gocql/gocql"


var CassandraSession *gocql.Session

func getSelectQuery(ClientId, UID, UUID, tableName, selectColumns string, sess *gocql.Session) (*gocql.Query, error) {
    
    selectQuery := fmt.Sprintf(qTamplate, selectColumns, tableName)
        query := sess.Query(selectQuery, ClientId, UID).Consistency(gocql.One)
    err = query.Exec()
    if err != nil {
        return query, err
    }
    
    return query, nil
}


func GetSeglistFromCassandra(reqId string, dataMap MapUserRequest) (models.IsInSegmentResponse, error) {
    resutMap := models.IsInSegmentResponse{}
    tableName := fmt.Sprintf("getter_%v", cid[len(cid) - 1])
    cqlsh := CassandraSession
    selectColums := "cohortid, is_deleted, cohortype"
    selectQueryObj, err := getSelectQuery(dataMap.ClientId, dataMap.UID, dataMap.UUID, tableName, selectColums, cqlsh)
    if err != nil {
        return resutMap, err
    }
    var id, deleted, cohortType int
    iter := selectQueryObj.Iter()
    for iter.Scan(&id, &deleted, &cohortType) {
        if deleted == 0 {
            if cohortType == 3 || cohortType == 2 {
                resutMap.ListId = append(resutMap.ListId, id)
            } else {
                resutMap.SegIds = append(resutMap.SegIds, id)
            }
        }
    }
    if err := iter.Close(); err != nil {
       return resultMap, err
    }
    return resutMap, nil
}


How to write unit test case in golang for this function GetSeglistFromCassandra which is using gocql without connecting to actual database if we can mock the gocql session creation, queries and iteration with example?

Summary
In my opinion, there is no way to write a unit test except for making an interface for gocql and its implementations. its implementations will be a wrapper struct for gocql and a mock for test.
The reason why we should use an interface and its wrapper struct is gocql provides their concrete types such as gocql.Session.
My suggestion
I suggest my approach to you. For that, I make your codes more simpler to handle.
simple.go
package mockgocql

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/gocql/gocql"
)

// SessionInterface allows gomock mock of gocql.Session
type SessionInterface interface {
    Query(stmt string, values ...interface{}) QueryInterface
}

// QueryInterface allows gomock mock of gocql.Query
type QueryInterface interface {
    Exec() error
    Consistency(c gocql.Consistency) QueryInterface
}

func simpleGetSelectQuery(ClientId, UID, UUID, tableName, selectColumns string, sessionInterface SessionInterface) (QueryInterface, error) {
    selectQuery := fmt.Sprintf(selectColumns, tableName)
    query := sessionInterface.Query(selectQuery, ClientId, UUID, UID).Consistency(gocql.One)

    err := query.Exec()
    if err != nil {
        return query, err
    }

    return query, nil
}

func simpleGetSeglistFromCassandra(cqlsh SessionInterface, reqId string) error {
    selectColums := "cohortid, is_deleted, cohortype"
    _, err := simpleGetSelectQuery("ClientId", "Uid", "Uuid", "tableName", selectColums, cqlsh)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return err
}


Explanations

Simplified functions simpleGetSelectQuery and simpleGetSeglistFromCassandra
Interfaces SessionInterface and QueryInterface
And CassandraSession should be injected as SessionInterface in simpleGetSeglistFromCassandra


From now on, you use gocql through these interfaces. For that, you should make its implementation, first.

impl.go
package mockgocql

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/gocql/gocql"
)

type SessionImpl struct {
    session *gocql.Session
}

type QueryImpl struct {
    query *gocql.Query
}

func (s *SessionImpl) Query(stmt string, values ...interface{}) QueryInterface {
    query := s.session.Query(stmt, values)
    return &QueryImpl{query: query}
}

func (q *QueryImpl) Exec() error {
    return fmt.Errorf("test")
}

func (q *QueryImpl) Consistency(c gocql.Consistency) QueryInterface {
    return q
}


Explanations

These codes are implementations for the interface to use.


These are the wrapper struct for the original gocql
Making a wrapper is a little tiring but it helps us make our own features besides the original gocql features.
Also it makes it possible for us to make a mock

mock.go
package mockgocql

import (
    "github.com/gocql/gocql"
)

type SessionMock struct {
}

type QueryMock struct {
}

func (s *SessionMock) Query(stmt string, values ...interface{}) QueryInterface {
    return &QueryMock{}
}

func (q *QueryMock) Exec() error {
    return nil
}

func (q *QueryMock) Consistency(c gocql.Consistency) QueryInterface {
    return q
}


Explanations.

These codes are mock implementations for the interface


It is a mock we want.
we can make any mock implementation as we want at a test.

simple_test.go
package mockgocql

import (
    "testing"

    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)

func Test_simpleGetSeglistFromCassandra(t *testing.T) {
    mockCassandra := SessionMock{}
    err := simpleGetSeglistFromCassandra(&mockCassandra, "test")
    assert.NoError(t, err)
}



We can make a test with a mock.
If we want various scenarios of the tests, we can make mocks according to its scenario.

Reference
I found others' trials here. https://github.com/gocql/gocql/issues/415
It seems they do similar things but it can be helpful to you.

I think the nimdrak's answer is good. But as a comparison, here I would like to provide another solution using xgo(a mocking library):
package test

import (
    "testing"

    "github.com/gocql/gocql"
    "github.com/xhd2015/xgo/runtime/mock"
)

func TestGetSeglistFromCassandra(t *testing.T){
    // bypass the Session.Query method with our mock
    mock.Patch((*gocql.Query).Exec, func(q *gocql.Query) error {
         // set result to q without actually exec anything
         q.SetResult(...)
         return nil
    })
    GetSeglistFromCassandra(test, ...)
}

This way no code change is required.
Learn more about xgo: https://github.com/xhd2015/xgo.
Disclaimer: I'm the creator of xgo, I've been using it in work.
